# How to fire a SubmitCompleteEvent for GWT's FormPanel when the content-type is not "text/html"

Tags: gwt, attachment, form-submit, formpanel

GWT's FormPanel fires a SubmitCompleteEvent only if the content-type of the response is of type "text/html", but my content-type is "text/csv" and of course my response is a csv file. I really need to do some actions after the submit was completed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The reason no event is fired is that browsers don't fire any event. And if they don't tell you what's happening when it's happening, you really can't tell. In other words, when GWT says it doesn't work, what it's really saying is that it's *impossible* to make it work (otherwise, GWT would have attempted to make it work).

You have no other choice but to change your server-side code and/or your UX.